# Create class dialogue in Android Studio 2.2 on Linux half hidden input

Tags: linux, android-studio, linux-mint

I'm on Linux Mint and have latest Android Studio 2.2 running on 14" FHD laptop (text scaling factor is set to 1.3). It's fine for other software and even for other dialogues in Android Studio, but the New - Java class window looks like this:
[New Class dialogue window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ids4.png)
Is there any way to fix it?

Comment: which JDK do you have installed? I experience similar issues with netbeans + openjdk, installing oracle jdk fixes the issue for me.

Comment: I'm using Oracle JDK 1.8.0_101 and it is set in JDK location in Project Structure settings. UPD: I tried now to switch to embedded JDK (android-studio/jre) - nothing changed.